# Jacoco plugin does not report coverage for renamed integration test class

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration, code-coverage

Let me show you the problem with the following use case:

Let's assume I have class `Example` and want to use the unit and integration test for that.
Once the unit tests in file `ExampleTest` (with methods annotated by `@Test`) is done, coverage report displays correct result.
Once the integration tests in file `ExampleTestInt` (with methods annotated by `@Test`) is done, coverage report does not display correct result. As if the class was excluded from the coverage process.

That means if I have just integration tests for `Example` class then I cannot see the correct result in coverage by jacoco.

Is there some way how to keep that `ExampleTestInt` class to be coverage similarly like in case of the unit test? I would like to keep the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the root problem was in wrong filename used for integration tests.

As per my observation the jacoco coverage plugin was looking for files with suffix `Test` and hence the file `ExampleTestInt` couldn't be seen by plugin.

Comment: So instead of adjusting the exclusions you have renamed the file? - the best solution in my opinion, also see https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming

Comment: Yes, I have. The article in the url looks fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure custom excludes like this:

```
<configuration>
  <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*Config.*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*Dev.*</exclude>
  </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Please checkout the jacoco docs: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html

Comment: I don't need to exclude anything. What I want to do is to include ExampleIntTest class to be executed by jacoo plugin similarly like in case of ExampleTest. But this doesn't happen. As if the jacoco couldn't find it and understand that it belongs under Example class.

Comment: if you do not want to exclude anything, leave the exclude list empty, i thought this was clear, sorry.

Comment: No problem, I've found out the solution. I will post it below.